# Create GUI windows like wizard windows for windows form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I like to create GUI like wizard for my program. I don't know how to explain. But the user just click "next" for next process and end with "Done" button at the last process. How do i can create this on in Windows Form C#?

eg: 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You just stack a bunch of panels on top of each other and place the content of each step in separate panels. Then, as the users clicks Next or Prev, you show/hide the different steps by setting the .Visible property of the panels accordingly.

Comment: when i Panel2.Visible = false at first. when i click next button. I write Panel2.Visible = true. But the panel do not show up. -_-"

Comment: You will probably have to set Panel1.Visible = false too

Answer (score 1):

For each of your wizard page, you can create a user control, for instance page1, page2, etc.
you can then add them into a collection:

```
List<Page> allPages= new List<Page>();
foreach( var page in allPages)
    page.hide();
```

And when you click "Next", you increment the counter:

```
void onNextClicked(...)
{
    current++;
    allPages[current].Show();
}
```

That is it. Of course, the above is the pseudo code. Cheers!